# How to replace values in dataframe based on values in another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a problem where I am trying to replace values in a dateframe with values from another dataframe, based on row and column indexing, but I cannot figure out how to get the replacements to reference the correct values. I am using Python.

I have this dataframe ("Param" for Parameter):

```
Color      Zone      Dependent.var        Param_1      Param_2     Param_3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Blue      A                 22               0            1           3
   Blue      A                 42               2            1           1
   Blue      A                 45               0            0           1                      
   Blue      B                 42               1            0           0
   Blue      B                 14               2            2           2
   Blue      B                 34               2            1           1
   Blue      C                 35               2            0           0
   Blue      C                 53               2            2           3
   Blue      C                 26               3            1           1
   Red       A                 36               3            2           1
   Red       A                 43               0            1           3 
   Red       A                 43               3            3           2
   Red       B                 24               2            1           1
   Red       B                 34               0            1           3 
   Red       B                 64               1            0           0                          
   Red       C                 54               0            2           1
   Red       C                 34               1            1           0 
   Red       C                 26               3            2           3
```

All the values in this dataframe under the Parameter clumns, as you can see, are 0, 1, 2, and 3. I need to replace them all with unique values corresponding to the Color, Zone, and Parameter. The "Dependent.var" column is ignored, and left as is.
Here is the replacements lookup table dataframe with the values that will replace the values in the initial dataframe:

```
  Parameter     Color    Zone      0    1    2    3
----------------------------------------------------
Parameter_1      Blue      A     1.2  1.3  1.4  1.5
Parameter_2      Blue      A     3.5  3.7  3.9  4.1
Parameter_3      Blue      A     2.1  2.2  2.3  2.4
Parameter_1      Blue      B     1.3  1.4  1.5  1.6
Parameter_2      Blue      B     3.7  3.8  4.1  4.3
Parameter_3      Blue      B     2.2  2.3  2.4  2.5
Parameter_1      Blue      C     2.2  3.3  4.4  5.5
Parameter_2      Blue      C     3.3  3.4  3.5  4.6
Parameter_3      Blue      C     2.6  2.7  2.8  2.9
Parameter_1      Red       A     3.3  3.4  3.5  3.6
Parameter_2      Red       A     3.8  3.9  4.0  4.2
Parameter_3      Red       A     1.3  1.4  1.5  1.6
Parameter_1      Red       B     3.1  3.2  3.3  3.4
Parameter_2      Red       B     3.2  3.4  4.6  4.8
Parameter_3      Red       B     0.9  1.1  1.3  1.5
Parameter_1      Red       C     3.2  3.3  3.2  3.1
Parameter_2      Red       C     3.9  4.0  4.1  4.3
Parameter_3      Red       C     0.8  1.2  1.6  2.0
```

I am trying to take my initial dataframe, and replace all the values in the Parameter columns with the values in the replacements lookup table dataframe, based on the corresponding Color, Zone, and Parameter. How can this be accomplished in python? I understand that there are replacement and mapping functions that can be used, but I am very confused about how to replace based on the proper indexing of Parameter, Color, and Zone.

Answer (score 0):

I would tackle this by restructuring your replacement lookup table so you can do a left join. Here is what your lookup table would look like.

| Color | Zone | Parameter | Param_ID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Blue | A | Parameter_1 | 0 | 1.2 |
| Blue | A | Parameter_1 | 1 | 1.3 |
| Blue | A | Parameter_1 | 2 | 1.4 |
| Blue | A | Parameter_1 | 3 | 1.5 |
| Blue | B | Parameter_1 | 0 | 1.3 |
| Blue | B | Parameter_1 | 1 | 1.4 |
| Blue | B | Parameter_1 | 2 | 1.5 |
| Blue | B | Parameter_1 | 3 | 1.6 |

and so on

You could do this transformation with `pandas.DataFrame.melt`

```
new_lookup = original_lookup.melt(
    id_vars=['Color', 'Zone', 'Parameter],
    value_vars=[0, 1, 2, 3],
    var_name='Param_ID',
    value_name='Value'
)
```

Then you could do left joins like

```
new_param = (
    param.merge(
        new_lookup.query('Parameter == "Parameter_1"'),
        how="left",
        left_on=['Color', 'Zone', 'Param_1'],
        right_on=['Color', 'Zone', 'Param_ID']
    ).merge(
        new_lookup.query('Parameter == "Parameter_2"'),
        how="left",
        left_on=['Color', 'Zone', 'Param_2'],
        right_on=['Color', 'Zone', 'Param_ID']
    ).merge(
        new_lookup.query('Parameter == "Parameter_3"'),
        how="left",
        left_on=['Color', 'Zone', 'Param_3'],
        right_on=['Color', 'Zone', 'Param_ID']
    )
)
```

### Full Working Example

Includes renaming and dropping columns in the merge step.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Color": ["Blue"] * 6,
    "Zone": ["A"] * 3 + ["B"] * 3,
    "Param_1": [0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2],
    "Param_2": [1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1],
    "Param_3": [3, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1]
})

lookup = pd.DataFrame({
    "Parameter": [f"Parameter_{i}" for i in range(1, 4)] * 2,
    "Color": ["Blue"] * 6,
    "Zone": ["A"] * 3 + ["B"] * 3,
    0: [1.2, 3.5, 2.1, 1.3, 3.7, 2.2],
    1: [1.3, 3.7, 2.2, 1.4, 3.8, 2.3],
    2: [1.4, 3.9, 2.3, 1.5, 4.1, 2.4],
    3: [1.5, 4.1, 2.4, 1.6, 4.3, 2.5]
})

new_lookup = lookup.melt(
    id_vars=['Color', 'Zone', 'Parameter'],
    value_vars=[0, 1, 2, 3],
    var_name='Param_ID',
    value_name='Value'
)

new_param = (
    df.merge(
        new_lookup.query('Parameter == "Parameter_1"').drop(columns=["Parameter"]).rename(columns={"Value": "Param_1_Value", "Param_ID": "Param_1"}),
        how="left",
        on=['Color', 'Zone', 'Param_1']
    ).merge(
        new_lookup.query('Parameter == "Parameter_2"').drop(columns=["Parameter"]).rename(columns={"Value": "Param_2_Value", "Param_ID": "Param_2"}),
        how="left",
        on=['Color', 'Zone', 'Param_2']
    ).merge(
        new_lookup.query('Parameter == "Parameter_3"').drop(columns=["Parameter"]).rename(columns={"Value": "Param_3_Value", "Param_ID": "Param_3"}),
        how="left",
        on=['Color', 'Zone', 'Param_3']
    )
)
print(new_param)
```

Output

```
  Color Zone Param_1 Param_2 Param_3  Param_1_Value  Param_2_Value  Param_3_Value
0  Blue    A       0       1       3            1.2            3.7            2.4
1  Blue    A       2       1       1            1.4            3.7            2.2
2  Blue    A       0       0       1            1.2            3.5            2.2
3  Blue    B       1       0       0            1.4            3.7            2.2
4  Blue    B       2       2       2            1.5            4.1            2.4
5  Blue    B       2       1       1            1.5            3.8            2.3
```

Comment: I see how you have restructured the lookup table, but you mentioned formatting the lookup table like my first table, which I am a bit confused about, since in my first table there is a separate column for each Parameter (Param_1, Param_2, and Param_3), but in your newly suggested lookup table, the Parameter types are all within one column, which I don't see matching the same structure as the initial dataframe/table. Would the join still work then? I ask because I would still need the output to be in the structure/format of the first dataframe/table.

Comment: Initially I thought the structure would be the same as your first table but as I worked through it I realized it is not exactly the same. I've edited the answer text to reflect this. The join should work, but it may give you extra columns you can then drop or rename as you need.

Comment: This suggestion definitely look like it will accomplish what I am looking for as your Full Working Example works perfectly. Though when using my actual research data, I have additional columns in my initial dataframe. I was assuming the rest of the values from the additional columns would just fall into place. Though upon running your code suggestion, particularly the "new_param" component, I encounter this error message: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'concat'`. Do you know why this might be? I tried replacing `.merge` with `.concat`, but that still did not work.

Comment: Ok, update, I realized I needed to rename my columns of my initial df, but now when trying to run the "new_param" component of the code, I receive this error message: `ValueError: You are trying to merge on int64 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat`, which does not make sense to me since I see that my columns are of the expected data type. Do you know how I might address this error?

Comment: In this example, the merge columns are `Color`, `Zone`, and either `Param_1`, `Param_2`, or `Param_3`.  I'm assuming you could easily verify that `Color` and `Zone` have the same dtype. That leaves `Param_1`, etc., which are created using `lookup.melt`. Here the column names of `lookup` are integers 0, 1, 2, and 3. But they could, inadvertently, be strings "0", "1", "2", "3". Then the `DataFrame.melt` method would create `Param_1` with a dtype of `object`. That might be the issue you are having.